# Paint.NET crashing when using the menus

Tags: windows, crash, paint.net

Whenever I go to the menus in Paint.NET it crashes with the error shown below.
I tried the newest version as well as version 2.7

Any ideas on what's going on?

> Exception details:
>   System.AccessViolationException:
>   Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication
>   that other memory is corrupt.    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs
>   e, ToolStripItemEventType met)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs
>   e, ToolStripItemEventType met)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs
>   mea)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&
>   m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks) 
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at
>   PaintDotNet.SystemLayer.MenuStripEx.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr
>   lparam)

Comment: Error reads: Exception details: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Do you have DEP enabled? Try adding Paint.NET to your exception list, or possibly even testing your RAM (though I think this is DEP related).

Comment: what operating system?

Comment: @studiohack: Considering it's a .NET app, and he hasn't mentioned WINE or Mono, it's a safe bet it's Windows.

Comment: "The first port of call would be to run a memory checker. This post has quite a lot of detail on how to do that." Does that fix the problem, let alone begin to narrow it down?

Answer (score 1):

Given that the error is:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

The first port of call would be to run a memory checker. [This post](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/check-for-bad-memory/) has quite a lot of detail on how to do that.

> [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) is by far the most popular amongst the memory checking crowd and works very well. It has a whole slew of tests that you pick and choose to run. The program was created in 1994 and was last updated in 2007, so it’s a bit old.
>
> [Prime95](http://mersenne.org/gimps/p95v2414.exe) is another memory checker, but one that has been updated more regularly and that works with multicore CPUs, which are becoming more prevalent these days. The program tests both the CPU and memory by using various stress tests, such as calculating large prime numbers.

The only other thing that springs to mind is that you're running out of memory and this is a misreported error. How much physical RAM do you have? What size is your swap file? And how big are the images you're manipulating?

Comment: 3.5 gigs of RAM.
Not sure on swap atm. Default windows size.

And this error occurs before I have opened up anything. :)

Comment: @bobber205 - OK, so it looks like memory corruption to me then.

Comment: Went down to version 2.5 and I'm able to use the menus. The machine is acting oddly slow, maybe I should run that test after all.